how to styling component from anther component in react js
enter image description here
Hello, how are you guys, I hope you find a solution to this problem. I want when I click on these bars the sidebar to disappear even though it's not in the same component Thanks for the help.
import {
  faMagnifyingGlass,
  faCartShopping,
  faMessage,
  faBell,
  faUser,
  faBars,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { useState } from "react";
import Sidebar from "./sidebar";
import Content from "./content";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

export default function Navbar(props) {

  
  
    function Toogle(){
        
      
      
    }
    
  return (
    <div className="item2" >
      <div className="leftContent">
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="iconsLeft" icon={faBars} onClick={Toogle}/>
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="iconsLeft" icon={faMagnifyingGlass} />
      </div>
      <div className="rightContent">
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="iconsRight" icon={faCartShopping} />
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="iconsRight" icon={faMessage} />
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="iconsRight" icon={faBell} />
        <div className="userAcount">
          <FontAwesomeIcon className="iconsRight" icon={faUser} />
          <p>issam</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


Welcome to StackOverflow! According to the website rules and to make us able to help you, it would be nice if you could create a code snippet that mimics your situation. Based on the image, it is unclear how your components are related, if they have any shared state, and if they have at least anything in common. It is pretty much possible that these two components even sit in two separate iframes (yes, I saw this in reality), which will be a VERY different story.
